# Add anchor to view exposed filters

Tags: views, search

I'm working on a site at the moment that has exposed filters for a search view using the Facet API. When a facet is selected it reloads the view with a GET parameter appended like in /recipes?f[0]=field_recipe_difficulty%3ABeginner.

Now, the results view is in a block about halfway down the page. Can I append an anchor like `#results-area` to the generated URL? I've looked into using AJAX but it's not really an option at the moment unless there's no way to use an anchor.

I am using Drupal 7.52 and the Views module version 7.x-3.15.